# How to access PHP table element with same name

Tags: php, mysql

I have this SQL query

```
   $query="SELECT * FROM FLIGHTTABLE INNER JOIN AirplaneTable ON FLIGHTTABLE.AIRPLANEID = AirplaneTable.AIRPLANEID
    INNER JOIN AIRPORTTABLE from_airport ON FLIGHTTABLE.AIRPORTDEPARTURE = from_airport.AIRPORTID
    INNER JOIN AIRPORTTABLE to_airport ON FLIGHTTABLE.AIRPORTARRIVAL = to_airport.AIRPORTID
    INNER JOIN ROUTETABLE route ON FLIGHTTABLE.AIRPORTARRIVAL = route.TOAIRPORTID && FLIGHTTABLE.AIRPORTDEPARTURE = route.FROMAIRPORTID
    WHERE $dateofdeparture_update $dateofarrival_update $airportofdeparture_update $airportofarrival_update $id_update$seats_update $status_update;";

    $res = mysql_query($query, GetMyConnection() );
    if (!mysql_num_rows($res))
    {
    if ($id)
{
        $results = array('success' => false, 'error' => 'Este voo não foi encontrado');
        } else {
               $results = array('success' => false, 'error' => 'Nenhum voo foi encontrado');
        }
          }
        else
        {

        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
            {
                //echo $row;
                $data[] = array(
                        'id'   => $row['FLIGHTID'],
                        'status'   => $row['FLIGHTSTATUS'],
                        'reason'   => $row['REASON'],
                        'airplane' => array(
                            'id' => $row['AIRPLANEID'],
                            'name' => $row['NAME']
                        ),
                        'departure' => $row['DATEOFDEPARTURE'],
                        'arrival' => $row['DATEOFARRIVAL'],
                        'fromairport' => $row['AIRPORTDEPARTURE'],
                        'fromairportname' => $row['NAMEOFAIRPORT'],
                        'toairport' => $row['AIRPORTARRIVAL'],
                        'toairportname' => $row['NAMEOFAIRPORT'],
                        'price' => $row['PRICE'],
                        'availableseats' => $row['AVAILABLESEATS'],
                        'price' => $row['PRICE'],
                        'photo' => $row['PHOTO'],
                );
            }

        $results = array('success' => true, 'data' => $data);
```

although `'fromairportname'` and `'toairportname'` should have different values they have the same value because `$row['NAMEOFAIRPORT']`,come out with the same value. How do I get the `$row['NAMEOFAIRPORT']` of the second inner join so that they show the actual departure and arrival datas?

Thanks

Comment: which one have the same names?

Comment: You have to use alias with those fields and instead of using * use the field name

Answer (score 1):

```php
$query="SELECT FLIGHTTABLE.FLIGHTID, 
        FLIGHTSTATUS, 
        REASON, 
        FLIGHTTABLE.AIRPLANEID, 
        DATEOFDEPARTURE, 
        DATEOFARRIVAL, 
        AIRPORTDEPARTURE, 
        from_airport.NAMEOFAIRPORT AS TONAMEOFAIRPORT, 
        AIRPORTARRIVAL, 
        to_airport.NAMEOFAIRPORT AS FROMNAMEOFAIRPORT,
```

Renaming the colunms like `from_airport.NAMEOFAIRPORT AS TONAMEOFAIRPORT` solved the problem.

Thanks All for the help

Comment: +1, remember to mark your own answer as the accepted answer, perhaps it can help other people another day.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of 'select *' you'll have to name each column in the query. Then you can alias them to something unique / available to PHP.

```
SELECT FLIGHTID, FLIGHTSTATUS, REASON, ...,
    AIRPORTDEPARTURE.NAMEOFAIRPORT fromAirport, AIRPORTARRIVAL.NAMEOFAIRPORT toAirport, ... 
   FROM FLIGHTTABLE
```

and so on

Comment: but how to access'NAMEOFAIRPORT´if they will have the same column name in the two inner joins?